# What are the semantics of Future::then?

Tags: rust

I’m confused by the semantics of the combinator `then`.

Intuitively, `a.then(|r| f(r))` is a future that when `a` finishes with `r`, resolves to `f(r)`. In other words, composing `f` after `a`. E.g. `a` reads a number from I/O and `f` doubles it. This makes sense and that’s been my mental model.

Digging deeper, in fact there’s more than that. The closure passed to `then` yields a `IntoFuture`, which means applying `f` to the result of `a` returns another future. The above understanding is incorrect then as `f(r)` is still not fully resolved.

From what I read in the documentation and the source code, it seems to be the following: `a.then(|r| f(r))` essentially keeps polling until the future `a` is resolved, then keep polling `f(r)` (which is also a future) until it resolves. Finally the whole thing is resolved.

Is this the right way to think about it? Why do we need a second layer of futures?

Comment: What do you mean by: a second layer of future?

Answer (score 3):

[`then`](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/futures-api-docs/0.3.0-alpha.5/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.then) does not wait for the future to be finished. It is lazy, as said by the doc:

> The closure is only run *after* successful completion of the `self` future.

It basically chains 2 futures. Suppose you have:

- one future `future_a` that "computes" a `a`,
- one method `foo` that takes an `a` and returns a `future_b`.

```
future_a.then(foo)
```

will be a future that merge those 2 futures to return a `future_b`

Comment: I think this is what `map()` does, while `then()` chains two futures.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Oh yes, you're right. This is a mistake. Do you want to answer, or should I edit my answer?

Comment: I don't have time to answer right now, so go ahead. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach I get that it is lazy. Using your example, suppose `t = future_a.then(foo)`. My question is: when `t.wait()` is called, `future_a` first gets resolved to "a", then *after* that, foo(a) is computed and returns a `future_b`. Is `future_b` is resolved as well, or it's returned as it?

Comment: @SvenMarnach now maybe i see it. that's nothing but the difference between `map(foo)` and `then(foo)`: `map` returns `foo(a)` while `then` resolves `foo(a)`.